# Applications of binary files

Tags: binaryfiles

This may be a basic question that I'm missing the answer to but would like your insights.

What are the purposes or applications of using binary files? I'm learning Python and ran across how to read/write to them. After some searching, I haven't found anything on why to use binary files, just syntax.

What comes to mind is that it might be faster/more efficient or that it has applications for encryption but I have no idea. Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Why binary files are needed](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap86/ch86_6.html) was the first search result on that phrase. It might be helpful.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you! That helped a lot. Guess all my searching was too python-centric, pulled up a lot on binary search trees and was a little lost